# How to deal with NA in two lists?

Tags: r, matrix, na

I have two lists and I want make them consistent in terms of `NA`. Put NA Whenever there is NA in one of the two lists without changing in anything else in the structure of the list.

```
set.seed(123)
m1 <- matrix(nrow=2,ncol=2,data=runif(4))
m1[1,1] <- NA
m2 <- matrix(nrow=2,ncol=2,data=runif(4))
m2[1,2] <- NA
lis <- list(m1, m2)
m1 <- matrix(nrow=2,ncol=2,data=runif(4))
m2 <- matrix(nrow=2,ncol=2,data=runif(4))
m2[2,1] <- NA
bis <- list(m1, m2)
```

I tried this but with no success `bis[is.na(lis)]=NA`

Desired output:

```
  > lis
[[1]]
          [,1]      [,2]
[1,]        NA 0.9568333
[2,] 0.4566147 0.4533342

[[2]]
         [,1]     [,2]
[1,] 0.9404673       NA
[2,] 0.0455565       NA

   > bis
 [[1]]
        [,1]      [,2]
[1,]        NA 0.9568333
[2,] 0.4566147 0.4533342

 [[2]]
         [,1]        [,2]
 [1,] 0.6775706        NA
 [2,] 0.5726334        NA
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an option:

```
z <- Map("|", lapply(lis, is.na), lapply(bis, is.na))
bis <- Map(function(mat, idx) {mat[idx] <- NA; mat}, bis, z)
lis <- Map(function(mat, idx) {mat[idx] <- NA; mat}, lis, z)
```

However, there may be faster / more efficient approaches due to the numerous `Map` and `lapply` calls.

---

For the case of >2 lists you can use the following approach (assuming that each list has the same length):

```
# create a named list - naming is important if you want to
# assign them back to the global environment later on
mylist <- list(lis = lis, bis = bis, kis = kis)

n <- max(lengths(mylist))
z <- lapply(1:n, function(i) {
  Reduce(`+`, Map(function(y) is.na(y[[i]]), mylist))>0
})

mylist <- lapply(mylist, function(mat) {
  Map(function(m, idx) {m[idx] <- NA; m}, mat, z)
})

# to assign them back to the global environment, run:
list2env(mylist, envir = .GlobalEnv)
```

Now your original lists are modified in the global environment.

**Sample data:**

```
set.seed(123)
n <- 4
lis <- list(
  m1 = matrix(nrow=n,ncol=n,data=sample(c(NA, 1:10), n*n, TRUE)), 
  m2 = matrix(nrow=n,ncol=n,data=sample(c(NA, 1:10), n*n, TRUE))
)
bis <- list(
  m1 = matrix(nrow=n,ncol=n,data=sample(c(NA, 1:10), n*n, TRUE)), 
  m2 = matrix(nrow=n,ncol=n,data=sample(c(NA, 1:10), n*n, TRUE))
)
kis <- list(
  m1 = matrix(nrow=n,ncol=n,data=sample(c(NA, 1:10), n*n, TRUE)), 
  m2 = matrix(nrow=n,ncol=n,data=sample(c(NA, 1:10), n*n, TRUE))
)
```

Comment: Replace the first line with: `z <- Map(function(...){dots <- as.list(...); arr <- do.call(abind, c(dots, along = 3)); apply(arr, 1:2, any)}, lapply(lis, is.na), lapply(bis, is.na))`.  I think that should work.  Probably slower though.  Needs the `abind` package.  Key is replacing `|` with `any`.

Comment: @Bazz, please go ahead and add it to your answer. I'll see if I can find a different approach

Comment: it is an adaptation of your answer, not mine.  `as.list` should just be `list`.

Comment: Or more simply, make a function `mor <- function(...) Reduce(`|`, list(...))` which will save the need for the `abind(..., along = 3)` and `apply`.

Answer (score 4):

Using `Map` to create a list of matrices with the `NA` positions as `NA`:

```
naposmtx <- Map(function(mtx1, mtx2){
    nasmtx <- mtx1 + mtx2 # because NA + non-NA = NA
    nasmtx[!is.na(nasmtx)] <- 0
    nasmtx
}, lis, bis)
```

Then:

```
lis <- Map(`+`, lis, naposmtx)
bis <- Map(`+`, bis, naposmtx)
```

Comment: Nice option, I benchmarked our solutions and they appear equally fast (+1)

Comment: Thank you.  I'll bear the `Map` function in mind - that's new to me.

Comment: It's just `mapply` with `simplify = FALSE`

Comment: Okay.  I think our solutions are really quite similar then.  (+1 to you)